# Admob banner wasn't show in ionic2

Tags: cordova, typescript, admob, ionic2

I actually work on a ionic2 app link to firebase. I try to add a banner with admob but when in try tu create banner nothing happen.

Template html:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar legoCollect hideBackButton="true">
  <button right menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Message</ion-title>

</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="page1">
    <button default (click)="createBanner()">Create Banner</button>
    <button secondary (click)="showBanner('bottom')">Show Banner</button>
    <button dark (click)="hideBanner()">Hide Banner</button>
    <button light (click)="showInterstitial()">Show Interstitial</button>
</ion-content>
```

Typscript file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {NavController, MenuController, Tabs, ViewController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, AuthProviders, AuthMethods} from 'angularfire2';
import {TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, LangChangeEvent, TranslateService, TranslatePipe, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {AdMob} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home-page/message-tab/message-tab.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class MessageTab {
  platform: Platform;
  admobId: any;
  adMobPosition: any;


  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.adMobPosition = {
      BOTTOM_CENTER: 8
    };
    this.admobId = {};
    this.admobId = {
      banner: 'addId',
    };
  }

  createBanner() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (AdMob) {

        AdMob.createBanner({
          adId: this.admobId.banner,
          isTesting: false,
          position: this.adMobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
          autoShow: true
        }).then(success => {
          console.log(success)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Admob failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });;

      }
    });
  }

  showInterstitial() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (AdMob) {
        AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
          adId: this.admobId.interstitial,
          autoShow: true
        });
      }
    });
  }

  showBanner(position) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (AdMob) {
        var positionMap = {
          "bottom": this.adMobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        };
        AdMob.showBanner(positionMap[position.toLowerCase()]);
      }
    });
  }
```

When i just try to create a banner with autoShow: true nothing happen and when i try showBanner a black rectangle appear but i have no problem for Interstitial.

Have you some idea about this problem?

Thank you

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No nothing this code just log an "OK"

Comment: Have you tried with this plugin? https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

Comment: nop, I was think that admob pro was better. But I think I i'll try this one.